# Remove Header and Footer in iframe

Tags: functions, iframe

Many people embed my website's pages in their websites as iframes. I want them to not take my footer, header and a specific division in those iframes. Since, footer, header and mentioned specific division is present in all of my pages.

What should I do? Should I add some code in my header or in my `functions.php` file?

Comment: There is no simple way to detect if request is coming from an *iframe*. You would have to devise a complex system of detection that persists across all subsequent session requests, not just the first and initial request.

Answer (score 1):

You could detect the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to detect whether the page is requested from an external server. If so, then you should load an alternative header and footer using `get_header()` and `get_footer()`. You'll need those calls to make sure all scripts and stylesheets are loaded, but you can remove the other content that make up the actual header and footer elements.

For example you could duplicate your current `header.php` to `header-iframe.php` and call the header with:

```
get_header('iframe');
```

The same thing goes for the footer. Create a file called `footer-iframe.php`  and call it using:

```
get_footer('iframe');
```

Just make sure your `header-iframe.php` contains everything up to the opening  tag, like this:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class('iframe'); ?>>
```

Your `footer-iframe.php` should be stripped of all excess content, like this:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The above snippets are just an example, but you get the idea. Calling the `get_header('iframe');` and `get_footer('iframe);` functions should be conditional based on the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable. This could be done using `preg_match` or any other native PHP comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a [specific template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) just for embedding? In your custom template, you could just remove the `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and `get_sidebar()` calls.